# How do I order bars in a grouped bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to order the bars in a grouped bar chart.

This is my tibble.

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3                
   number    name                   prop     
       <dbl> <chr>                  <int>    
           1 Dog                     0.0664  
           1 Cow                     0.0628  
           1 Pig                     0.0166  
           1 Garden                  0.0163  
           2 Moose                   0.0619  
           2 Cliff                   0.0517  
           2 Hike                    0.0214  
           2 Dog                     0.0147  
           2 Cow                     0.0141  
           3 Pig                     0.0615  
           3 Garden                  0.0245  
           3 Moose                   0.0135  
           3 Cow                     0.0132
```

I'd like to make a grouped bar chart where the groups are sorted from greatest to least for values of `prop`. I want the groups to be sorted from greatest to least, so the x-axis should read from left to right: `1, 2, 3` and then, within each group, I want it to be greatest to least.

The bars for the number `1` should be `Dog` then `Cow` then `Pig` then `Garden`

This is what I tried.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

tib.ready <- tib %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, prop, sum)) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, prop, sum)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(number = fct_reorder(factor(number), prop, sum))
```

I tried the solution that Matias Andina linked to.

```
tib_ready <- with(tib_ready, 
       tib_ready[order(name, -as.numeric(prop)), ])

tib_ready %>%
ggplot(aes(number, prop, fill = name, label = name)) +
      geom_col(position = "dodge") +
      coord_flip()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the order of dodged bars in ggplot2 barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721536/changing-the-order-of-dodged-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: I added my attempt to use that solution into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already ordered all the rows by the appropriate groups you could add another column that represents the order within the groups and use the `group` aesthetic argument. That should order them as desired within the `number` group.

```
tib.ready <- tib %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, prop, sum)) %>% 
  group_by(number) %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(name, prop, sum)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(number = fct_reorder(factor(number), prop, sum))

ggplot(tib.ready, aes(x = number, y = prop, fill = name, group = rank, label = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

edit: Updated to just use the `rank` variable

Comment: This worked, can you please explain why this works?

Comment: the `group` aes overrides existing default ordering in your input dataframe, using the new column you're manually setting the ordering

Comment: actually i realized you already have a rank variable... you can use that instead of the new `grp_order` variable, see edit

Comment: Great, now how do I get the legend to have the same order as the bars?

Comment: the order of the legend also uses the default ordering in the data.frame, so you can modify the order there, or you can set them by using `scale_fill_discrete` or `guides`

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(prop = as.double(prop), rank = as.numeric(rank)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = number, y = reorder(prop, rank), fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  ylab("Prop") +
  coord_flip()
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), name = c("Dog", "Cow", "Pig", "Garden", "Moose", 
    "Cliff", "Hike", "Dog", "Cow", "Pig", "Garden", "Moose", "Cow"
    ), prop = c(0.0664, 0.0628, 0.0166, 0.0163, 0.0619, 0.0517, 0.0214, 
    0.0147, 0.0141, 0.0615, 0.0245, 0.0135, 0.0132), rank = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me the following error: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

Comment: @Cauder try it on the sample you provided. It works. Then try and make your provided sample more reflective of your true data.

Comment: @Cauder Try the edited solution where we explicitly coerce the vectors to the correct type.